# Show alert with 'ok' and 'Cancel ' button from c# code

Tags: javascript, c#, alert

I have a requirement to show a popup message on save button click which is a HTML control and has code to save the data in C#.
Depending on data entered by the user,if entered data is not correct then I want to show a popup message with "Please check your data "with 'ok' and 'cancel' buttons on the popup.
If user select 'OK' button then user will correct the data an try to save again.
If user selects cancel then I have to clear the data entered by the user.

I am able to show the popup message using ,

```
string message = "Please check the data entered.";

System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
sb.Append("alert('");
sb.Append(message);
sb.Append("')};");
sb.Append("</script>");
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
```

but this code is not serving my purpose to show 'OK' And 'Cancel' buttons on popup.I am new to .net .Need some help.

Comment: you want a `confirm`

Comment: Try using `confirm();` instead of `alert();` .

Comment: change line `sb.Append("alert('");` to `sb.Append("confirm('");`

Comment: Thank you all changing sb.Append("alert('"); to sb.Append("confirm('"); did the trick for me.But how to find which button did user selected?

Comment: Note that you need to make sure your `message` doesn't contain any `'`. Or use [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx) on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("confirm('ok')");
```

Comment: A brief explanation would be useful for OP.